# Is it necessary to know flash designing for flex3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex3

I am from a programming background ,and newbie to flex3 . i would like to learn flex3 and develop some application using rails and flex3 .  Is it necessary to know flash in order to learn flex3 or just learning Action script 3 would do ?  .Can anybody tell what are the prerequisites to learn flex3 . Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably learn how to use AS3, but most of the Flex learning paths I've encountered so far included both MXML and AS3.

You do not need to know anything about the Flash design tools (Flash CS3/4) to develop Flex applications.

While non-Flex applications can also be developed using Flex builder, these have nothing to do with the Flash design tool.

**Summary:**

Flex: Framework built on top of AS3. Use Flex Builder to develop these applications (current version is 3, the next version is going to be called Flash Builder 4 because the Adobe marketing team has to justify its existence).

**Links:**

AS3 - http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=Part6_ProgAS_1.html

Flex - http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/mxml_1.html#192432

**Books:**

Essential Actionscript 3.0 - [http://www.amazon.com/Essential-ActionScript-3-0-Colin-Moock/dp/0596526946/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1250070076&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596526946)

Programming Flex 3 - [http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Flex-Comprehensive-Creating-Applications/dp/0596516215/ref=pd_sim_b_8](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516215)

As for videos, the net is full of them, but since I learn much faster from books, I've never bothered to look for any videos. It does seem however that adobe has some new thing on their Developer Center. Take a look at: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/learn/learningpath.html#type=role&role=programmer

The help system that comes with Flex Builder 3 is exceptionally good as well (as opposed to most other language dedicated IDEs I've encountered so far). I suggest you get a copy of FB3 and install it. Things tend to get a lot simpler once you have a working environment to experiment with, especially when the IDE offers comprehensive documentation (under the help -> help contents menu).

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the details could you share some resource links like ebooks or videos , where i could start learning flex3

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "knowing flash". You don't have to know anything about how to do graphic design in flash, because flex is its own beast. You do have to know about the data structures and API's provided by the flash plugin, and about actionscript.

Answer (score 0):

Its not necessary if you only want to learn Flex... if you want to be a good Flash developer though, I would advice you to learn about the whole platform (Flash IDE included).

Answer (score 0):

Lior Cohen's explanation is very good.  If you are familiar with things like PHP or VB.net, you will likely be better suited to using Flex Builder than using Flash.  The two are very different beasts and moving between the two can hurt your brain.  Using the MXML and AS3 structures in Flex, you can embed swf files that were built with Flash and in some instances, you may find yourself importing some of the libraries from Flash but you don't need Flash in order to work in Flex and learn how things work.

If you learn by doing rather than by reading about how things should work, the livedocs can be a bit frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation a few years ago where I moved from Java Web / PHP5 development to Flex. If you are good with MXML and ActionScript 3 and familiar with CSS you should be good to go. Knowing Flash is not a prerequisite for Flex Development.